# Ejecutar un archivo php de manera secuencial

Tags: php, mysql, array

Mi pregunta quizá suene un poco ambigua pero lo que necesito es ejecutar el mismo archivo php siguiendo el orden de un array. 
Mi array es el siguiente, que en realidad es el ID de trabajadores:

```
$id_trx = $_POST['id'];
```

Lo cual imprime:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 [4] => 7 [5] => 8 [6] => 9 [7] => 11 [8] => 12 [9] => 13 [10] => 14 [11] => 17 [12] => 18 [13] => 19 [14] => 20 [15] => 21 [16] => 26 [17] => 27 [18] => 29 [19] => 32 [20] => 35 [21] => 39 [22] => 41 [23] => 42 [24] => 44 [25] => 84 [26] => 95 [27] => 123 [28] => 124 [29] => 131 [30] => 138 [31] => 141 [32] => 177 [33] => 205 [34] => 206 [35] => 208 [36] => 209 [37] => 211 [38] => 220 [39] => 229 [40] => 234 [41] => 243 [42] => 244 [43] => 261 [44] => 270 [45] => 272 [46] => 278 [47] => 280 [48] => 286 [49] => 291 [50] => 292 [51] => 294 )
```

Ahora bien, el problema radica en ejecutar un archivo php por cada uno de los ID antes descritos, es decir, que cuando el archivo php termine de ejecutar el ID 1, pase al 2 y luego al 4 y así sucesivamente. Lo que hace el archivo php, es guardar generar y guardar (mysql) información de muchas tablas asociadas y es por eso que no subí ese archivo ya que es muy extenso y complicado de explicar. 
Hay alguna forma de realizar este proceso. 
Agradezco cualquier orientación al respecto.

Comment: No tienes que ejecutar el archivo PHP por cada `ID` del array. Dentro de un código PHP primero lees el array y luego en un [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php): por cada elemento `ID`, llamar a una función que contiene la rutina deseada. Esa función tendrá como [argumento](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php) el `ID`, el cual se lo enviarás en el llamado a la función.

Answer (score 0):

Con un `foreach`

```
<?php
    $array = Array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 4, 3 => 5, 4 => 7, 5 => 8 );

foreach($array as $r){
    echo 'Este es el ID => '.$r.'<br>';
}

// Resultado
Este es el ID => 1
Este es el ID => 2
Este es el ID => 4
Este es el ID => 5
Este es el ID => 7
Este es el ID => 8
```

Y listo. Ojo que tu array tiene fallos, fijate en la estructura del mio...